# Как разрезать bmp картинку в C#

Tags: c#, .net

Всем привет. Есть изображение `bmp`. На нём 9 цифр. Как можно разрезать это изображение, чтобы в каждой части было по цифре (т.е. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)? 
Фон белый, цифры чёрные.

Comment: Ширина области с каждой цифрой одинакова?

Comment: Просто умоляю если нашел решение отправь пожалуйста

Comment: @Tikhon 
https://pastebin.com/BRRq4xn1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из решений *"на коленке"* - выбрать каждый пиксель не-белого цвета и объединить все такие пиксели *в систему непересекающихся множеств.* Т.е, если мы идем от пикселя в любую сторону и встречаем там такой же пиксель не-белого цвета, то он добавляется именно к этому множеству.

*Если все это правильно сделано, то получить итоговые части изображения можно просто найдя `bounding box` для каждого непересекающегося множества.*

Очевидно, что метод будет плохо работать в случае неоднородного фона и в случае накладывающихся друг на друга чисел.

---

Более громоздкий, однако и более точный вариант - использовать библиотеку в духе [**Tessnet.**](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)

Comment: Буду разбираться :)